# How do I track the number of lines added/deleted in an emacs session?

Tags: text-editing

I am looking towards tracking the number of lines of text that I have added or removed in a session of emacs, is there any simple way to do this?

If not what would be the right direction towards writing a plugin that would help me do this?

Comment: Do you just want the net added or removed, without needing to know how many were added vs how many removed in the same session? Do you need this for all buffers together or individually? The question is unclear. Anyway, you can use function `count-lines` at `point-max` anytime to get the number of lines in a given buffer. There is also `count-lines-region`.

Comment: Count of lines added, and count of lines removed separately. It should be in one session - inclusive of all buffers.

Comment: Please don't clarify your question in a comment. Comments can be deleted at any time. Please clarify the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it for a project by creating a function

```
(defun show-code-delta ()
   (message (shell-command-to-string "git diff --shortstat")))
```

I bound this to `C-c C-c`

Whenever I do a `C-c C-c` I get to know the lines changed from the last commit and it gives me a rough idea of how many changes I have done in a session.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using git, you might like to look at git-gutter mode: https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter

Comment: That's a sublime plugin...  This site is about Emacs.

Comment: I guess this link was intended: https://github.com/syohex/emacs-git-gutter